# Ender 3 pro Bed won't heat over 85 °C and gives E1 error

Tags: creality-ender-3, heated-bed

We have a brand new 3 month old Ender 3 Pro and we want to print ABS, but, unfortunately the printer trips and gives `error E1`.

We limited the error to the bed: since when we heat up bed it gets stuck on 85 °C for while and suddenly through the `E1 Error`. It seems the bed won't heat up over 85 °C.

Comment: What is the actual message, is it `E1 Heating Failed`? If so, E1 is indicating that the hotend heating failed, not the bed!

Comment: @OscarI am getting  Heating Failed: E1, Print Halted. The reason I  is because I preheat nozzle by it self and I did not get any error, but when Pre heat the bed by it self I am getting E1 error.

Comment: Heating the bed and hotend is not related, unless your PSU is delivering insufficient power, e.g. when in incorrect mode (115 or 230 V). Please describe in more detail the steps you did, how hot the bed is set, how hot the hotend and when they are heating. E.g. through G-code, or the steps you did manually, please do this by [edit].

Comment: Be careful printing ABS indoors,  a lot of VOCs are released which are bad for your lungs. Also temps above 240C can cause the Teflon lining in thr ender 3 to release toxic fumes. The bed error is probably due to not enough power in the bed and losing heat to environment too quickly. Closed  build chamber will help